# How to recover deleted files on Iomega NAS ix2-200 CloudEdition - Linux based system with Raid1 and JBOD

Tags: nas, raid-1, file-recovery, jbod

I deleted some video files by mistake on my Iomega NAS ix2-200 StorCenter Cloud Edition. Linux based system with Raid1 and JBOD
I stopped writing any action on the StorCenter.

How can I recover these files ? there is no trash on the StorCenter !

I tried some free software from my Windows laptop but they can't find my Nas on the network to scan for the deleted files.

A friend told me to connect the Nas to an Linux Ubuntu machine to recover the files.
How to connect the NAS directly to the linux machine ? with the LAN cable ? and how should I proceed to recover?

(the iomega support don't help me much if I don't send the nas to them)

Thank you, it is very urgent, any help appreciated

Regards

I own a laptop with Windows 8; (and Ubuntu)
Apple AirPort Extreme router;
and an Iomega StorCenter ix2-200 Cloud Edition.

Comment: I have the same problem, and have been advised to try R-Studio or UFS explorer. Have not done so yet.

Answer (score 1):

UFS explorer is working fine.

Just connect one drive to a computer. Run UFS to recover files to another drive. Pretty simple and straightforwards.

After recovery copy the files via network to the NAS.